# Python - how can I reference a class variable or method from within the __init__ method?

Tags: python, class-method

I have a hierarchy of objects in a python module as follows:

```
class BaseObject(object):
    initialized = False

    def __init__(self):
        self._initialize()

    @classmethod
    def _initialize(cls):
        print "cls.initialized = "+str(cls.initialized)
        if not cls.initialized:
            cls.x = 1
            cls.initialized = True

class ObjectOne(BaseObject):
    @classmethod
    def double_x(cls):
        cls.x = cls.x * 2
        print cls.x

class ObjectTwo(BaseObject):
    @classmethod
    def triple_x(cls):
        cls.x = cls.x * 3
        print cls.x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    obj_1 = ObjectOne()
    obj_1.double_x()
    obj_2 = ObjectTwo()
    obj_2.triple_x()
```

When I run this module I would like the output to be:

```
cls.initialized = False
2
cls.initialized = True
6
```

But what I get is:

```
cls.initialized = False
2
cls.initialized = False
3
```

What do I not understand?

Comment: This reads a bit more like Ruby than Python.  There are different conventions for the latter as opposed to the former.

Comment: @Makoto that's interesting. Can you explain further? What conventions did I violate?

Comment: I wouldn't call them "violations" per se, as this is valid Python regardless.  It's the case though, when one has a class method, they pass `self` through to the method instead of using the `@clsmethod` decorator.  There's also no need for a `self._initialize()` method, as that's the role of `__init__()` to begin with.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm trying to understand.  `__init__()` is an instance method.  I want the initialization to take place in a class method.

Comment: Your example code has really bad "code smell". Specifically the whole bit of setting a class variable from an instance constructor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use the full classname to *set* class variables. `cls` in `double_x` and `tripple_x` will refer to subclasses (`ObjectOne` and `ObjectTwo`, respectively), and setting attributes on those subclasses will store *new* variables, not alter the class variable `BaseObject.x`. You can *only* alter base class variables by *directly* accessing them.

Using your code, we get:

```
>>> obj_1 = ObjectOne()
cls.initialized = False
>>> obj_1.double_x()
2
>>> obj_2 = ObjectTwo()
cls.initialized = False
>>> obj_2.triple_x()
3
>>> BaseObject.x
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'BaseObject' has no attribute 'x'
>>> BaseObject.initialized, ObjectOne.initialized, ObjectOne.x, ObjectTwo.initialized, ObjectTwo.x
(False, True, 2, True, 3)
```

What happened is that in `_initialize()`, `cls` was set to `ObjectOne` or `ObjectTwo`, depending on what instance you created, and each subclass got their *own* copies of the variables `initialized` and `x`.

Using `BaseObject._initialize()` (to ensure that `BaseObject` is initialized, and not the subclasses) gives:

```
>>> obj_1 = ObjectOne()
cls.initialized = False
>>> obj_1.double_x()
2
>>> obj_2 = ObjectTwo()
cls.initialized = True
>>> obj_2.triple_x()
3
>>> BaseObject.x, ObjectOne.x, ObjectTwo.x
(1, 2, 3)
>>> BaseObject.initialized
True
>>> 'x' in ObjectOne.__dict__
True
>>> 'initialized' in ObjectOne.__dict__
False
>>> 'initialized' in ObjectTwo.__dict__
False
```

So now `_initialize()` used `BaseObject` as the target to set `initialized` and the initial value for `x`, but `double_x` and `triple_x` still used their own subclasses to set the *new* value of `x` and are not sharing that value through `BaseObject`.

The only option you have to set class variables on a specific base class is to refer to it directly in *all* class methods:

```
class BaseObject(object):
    initialized = False
    def __init__(self):
        BaseObject._initialize()

    @classmethod
    def _initialize(cls):
        print "cls.initialized = "+str(cls.initialized)
        if not cls.initialized:
            cls.x = 1
            cls.initialized = True
class ObjectOne(BaseObject):
    @classmethod
    def double_x(cls):
        BaseObject.x = BaseObject.x * 2
        print cls.x

class ObjectTwo(BaseObject):
    @classmethod
    def triple_x(cls):
        BaseObject.x = BaseObject.x * 3
        print cls.x
```

which would give:

```
>>> obj_1 = ObjectOne()
cls.initialized = False
>>> obj_1.double_x()
2
>>> obj_2 = ObjectTwo()
cls.initialized = True
>>> obj_2.triple_x()
6
```

Note that I called `BaseObject._initialize()` to make sure that `cls` is `BasObject` and not a subclass. Then, when *setting* `x` the `double_x` and `triple_x` methods still refer directly to `BaseObject` to ensure that the variable is set directly on the base class. When *reading* the value of `x` the above example still uses `cls`, which uses the class MRO to find `x` on the base class when not set locally.

Comment: Thanks.  But I know that the `_initialize()` method, which I have clearly designated as a @classmethod, is being called by the line `self._initialize()` because its print statement is printing.  If it is not the class method that is being called, what is causing the print statement to print?

Comment: @JonCrowell: You are quite correct; even on instances class methods still will pass in the class instead.

Comment: @JonCrowell: There, after some more editing, that should be a much better answer to explain what you are seeing.

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues.first of all in order to call the class method inside the class,you must use the **COMPLETE** name of the class:`BaseObject._initialize()`
second of all, every time you make a new instance of `ObjectOne` or `ObjectTwo`,you are overwriting the `BaseObject.x` within its environment,so others use the initialized `x` attribute instead of the changed one.to fix this you must change two lines:

`cls.x = cls.x *` 2 To `BaseObject.x = cls.x * 2`

and

`cls.x = cls.x * 3` To `BaseObject.x = cls.x * 3`